# Does dart support non-local variables?

Tags: python, dart, variables, scope

For example in Python we have a non-local feature:

> The nonlocal keyword is used to work with variables inside nested functions,
> where the variable should not belong to the inner function.
> Use the keyword nonlocal to declare that the variable is not local.
>
> The nonlocal statement declares that whenever we change the binding of the name var, the binding is changed in the first frame in which the var is already bound. Recall that without the nonlocal statement, an assignment statement would always bind a name in the first frame of the current environment. The nonlocal statement indicates that the name appears somewhere in the environment other than the first (local) frame or the last (global) frame.

Is there something similar to this in Dart?

Here is a code sample from Python:

```py
def make_withdraw(balance):
    """Return a withdraw function that draws down balance with each call."""
    def withdraw(amount):
        nonlocal balance                 # Declare the name "balance" nonlocal
        if amount > balance:
            return 'Insufficient funds'
        balance = balance - amount       # Re-bind the existing balance name
        return balance
    return withdraw
```

Pseudo-translation to Dart where I can't use `nonlocal`:

```dart
makeWithdraw(balance) {
  //Return a withdraw function that draws down balance with each call.
  withdraw(amount) {
    var nonlocal balance; //Declare the name "balance" nonlocal
    if (amount > balance){return 'Insufficient funds';}
    balance = balance - amount    //rebind the existing balance name
    return balance;}
  return withdraw;
}
```

When I type `nonlocal` here it's giving me error.

For context, this is where I am learning from and trying to convert the Python code to Dart:

https://composingprograms.com/pages/24-mutable-data.html#local-state

Comment: This would be better with a Dart code sample and illustration of how you’d want to handle a specific situation in Dart, than a lengthy Python quote and tag.

Comment: @deceze i edited the question and added in some code where the problem came up..When i try nonlocal in dart its giving me error since nonlocal keyword don't exist in dart.

Comment: What you have shown isn't Python code. Did you mean to say that this is Dart?

Comment: oh yea i converted into pseudo-dart becuase well i cant execute it just yet, i will also post the python code

Comment: Well, I don’t know Dart, but in Javascript for instance you wouldn’t need any special keyword there. The variable would be available and mutable simply by lexical scope. Are you sure you need anything special here (again: I don’t know Dart scoping rules)…?

Comment: @deceze I don't know much about scoping rules, for example if python is lexically scoped as well it should not need nonlocal variable right,                                               Python Particulars. This pattern of non-local assignment is a general feature of programming languages with higher-order functions and lexical scope. Most other languages do not require a nonlocal statement at all. Instead, non-local assignment is often the default behavior of assignment statements. i will try to find a workaround in dart

Comment: I don't know Dart, but this [late](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables) might be close to a non-local variable ?

Comment: @Luuk seems like dart automatically makes it nonlocal and doesn't need any keyword at all!

Comment: Python requires the `nonlocal` statement for disambiguation, because variable scope is defined by where a variable is being assigned. JS uses `var`/`let` to explicitly define variable scope, thus an additional keyword isn’t needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart is a [*lexically-scoped*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope) language with explicit variable declarations.  As with other programming languages that descended from C syntax, variables are scoped *where they are declared*. (Python needs `global` and `nonlocal` keywords because Python does not require explicit variable declarations, and without those keywords would implicitly declare new local variables.)

If you want a non-local variable, just declare it outside of the local scope.  For example:

```dart
int globalVariable = 0;

void foo(int variableLocalToFoo) {
  int anotherVariableLocalToFoo = 42;

  void bar(int variableLocalToBar) {
    int anotherVariableLocalToBar = variableLocalToFoo + variableLocalToBar;
  }

  if (true) {
    int variableLocalToBlock = 9;
  }
}

class SomeClass {
  int memberVariable = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
makeWithdraw(balance) {
  //Return a withdraw function that draws down balance with each call.
  withdraw(amount) {
    balance; 
    if (amount > balance) {
      return 'Insufficient funds';
    }
    balance = balance - amount;
    print(balance);
    return balance;
  }

  return withdraw;
}

nonlocalTest() {
  var wd = makeWithdraw(20);
  wd(5);
  wd(1);
  wd(5);

}
```

Ok it seems this program works fine in dart even without nonlocal variable! It seems This pattern of non-local assignment is a general feature of programming languages with higher-order functions and lexical scope..! So nonlocal is not needed in dart, but the same program will not work in python without nonlocal keyword!

Comment: You can remove the line with just `balance;` on it, it doesn't do anything.